# How to store files into a folder in selenium python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When I open a url with selenium web driver and want to download file to a specific folder. I tried below code but not working.

```
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    # etc...

    # declare prefs
    prefs = {"media.autoplay.enabled": False, "network.proxy.autoconfig_url": pac_url,
             "network.proxy.autoconfig_url.include_path": True}

    # add prefs
    chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromdriver85/chromedriver.exe", chrome_options=options)
```

Any better and standard solution. Thank You

Comment: Which files are you asking about?

Comment: did you tried setting this --> `prefs = {"download.default_directory" : "/some/path"}`?

Comment: @vitaliis, need to automatically download to specified folder.

Comment: @Dev, I'm getting error at ***chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)***. Error is chromeOptions is not available.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the files to the default folder and then copy or move them to the desired folder.